# UseUnsafeHeaderParsing setting in .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, system.net

I used to use this setting in the full .Net framework to deal with some unsafe headers returned by a server I'm reaching out to.

```
 <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
 <system.net>
```

I can't really find a way to do the same in .Net core. (console app)

Any help?

Comment: Hi Alessandro , did you find any fix for your probelm ? can you share it please ?

Comment: Hey there, not really. I was actually able to remove it as after a functionality review of my system I didn't really need to do that anymore. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question and remembered a post that may help you on the microsoft forum

[Link forum microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff098248-551c-4da9-8ba5-358a9f8ccc57/how-do-i-enable-useunsafeheaderparsing-from-code-net-20?forum=netfxnetcom)